# Dialog Box Property Value Editor

Tags: wpf, user-controls

i am new to WPF and i want to create user control with Dialog Box Property Value Editor in VB.NET.
i find this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892994.aspx) in C# and rewrite it to VB.NET but it does not work. Is creating property value editor in VB.NET somehow special, because i can`t find examples in VB.NET

thanks

Comment: you can't find examples bc most WPF is in C#

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is an old question, but I fought with the same (?) problem and it took me one day to figure it out, so maybe this helps someone else.
At the end it was quite simple. I used the example mentioned above to wrote my own control and first it didn't work, the editor was not used. Thanks to [this article](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/extensibility-series-wpf-silverlight-design-time-code-sharing-part-i/) I learned, that there is a naming convention. You have to name your design time assembly like your control and add '.design' at the end. Only then this assembly will be used as a design time assembly.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's nothing special about writing property editors or any other kind of control or component in VB.NET versus C#.  It's just that a lot of WPF samples are written in C#, perhaps because the VB.NET community has been more conservative about adopting WPF *[citation needed]*.  You should do just fine by translating the C# code you find to VB in the normal way; you shouldn't need to change the XAML of course.